# EF Core assigns negative sequence number to autoincrement int field

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

When the Attach method on the context is called to attach an object to the context a negative sequence number is supposed to be temporarily assigned to the Identity property. In my case the value appears to be permanent resulting in an error when finally saving the object to database.

```
 public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        entity.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _context.SyncObjectState<TEntity>(entity);
    }

 public class Tier:Entity
{
    public Tier()
    {

    }
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TierID { get; set; }
    public string CountryID { get; set; }
    public string TierName { get; set; }
    public int TierNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AdministrativeStructure> AdministrativeStructures { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Entityframework core 1.1.0 with MSSQL Server 2016

Comment: What is type 'Tier'?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Define "random" - is it the same 'random' number every time, or a different number for each instantiation of `Tier`?

Comment: a different number for each occasion and it is always negative

Comment: why don't you put a break point at the setter and check which method/thread (look up your stacktrace) update your TierId?

Comment: @Rex Ok, I will get to it

Comment: @JuliusTetteh Do you Database give the Primary Key Values by itself or do you need to do so?

Comment: The database autogenerates the ID. But per @Rex suggestion I narrowed the problem down to this line " public virtual void SyncObjectState<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IObjectState
        {
            Entry(entity).State = StateHelper.ConvertState(entity.ObjectState);
        }" . Everything works fine until the execution gets here. the value then changes from "0" to some random negative number

Comment: I've noticed that too. It happens when the entity is attached to the db context (by using `Add` or some other method), in which case EF Core assigns negative sequence number and `PropertyEntry.IsTemporary` is set to `true`. But it shouldn't cause issues with inserting data into the database.

Comment: @IvanStoev Unfortunately in my case it is causing a lot of headache

Comment: Changing _dbSet.Attach(entity); to _dbSet.Add(entity); solved the problem. Still wondering why. Thank you guys all for the support

Answer (score 2):

Lets see. If you create a class with properties like this and won't give it any Input, the Integer will have following Value:

`0`

Code:

```
class Program
{   
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      tmpClass testClass = new tmpClass();
      Debug.WriteLine(testClass.IntTest);


  }

  public class tmpClass
  {
      public int IntTest { get; set; }
  }
}
```

As you can see I didn't manipulate anything. The Value ist zero, `0`, the default Value from a Int. You said you use `TierID` as Primary Key Value. Does your Table know how to handle this, like it will give it a ID or do you need to give it a ID? Maybe thats where the Error occurs. Wrong Primary Key.

In your case it seems the Database Generation doesn't seem to work right.

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int TierId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I dont have to provide any ID. the database does that. But I think I have been able to detect where the problem is coming from. I used a repository pattern framework (URF), did some minor modification so it can work with dotnet core and the line here is what is creating the problem "public virtual void SyncObjectState<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IObjectState
        {
            Entry(entity).State = StateHelper.ConvertState(entity.ObjectState);
        }"

Comment: Something happens at this line that seems to affect only the "TierID" changing it to a negative number and I have not the slightest inkling what is happening. I could send you my version of the library if that would help you help me out here

Comment: Ah yes. Okay thanks for that answer. How about you look at the Solution @Tazbir Bhuiyan found some years ago.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333916/failed-to-save-data-using-ef6-error-originalvalues-cannot-be-used-for-entities

Comment: I followed the example in the link you provided but it didnt work

Comment: I would like to use the current date and time in micro seconds to generate a unique string of 8 characters to use as the TierID and forget about using the int type and the autoincrement features. Can you help me with that

Comment: @JuliusTetteh You said you did some modification? Could you show us these modificated classes? (Edit it into your Question). I would not recommend using a 8 characters `String` as `Primary Key`. When the table gets bigger or you create complicate statements or functions, the database will take longer to find what you seek and the capacity will be higher than usual.

Comment: The URF repository framework was designed with support for EntityFramework 6 which could not work well on .net core platform. So I simly just went through the library class by class and created .netcore compatible versions. with very liitle change nothing substantially different. Except where I had to drop "ObjectContext" and did some retrofitting that I didnt quite understand but it all worke well until the autoincrement issue came up

Comment: @JuliusTetteh I searched a little bit and added something to my answer.

Comment: I have already done that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132513/discussion-between-julius-tetteh-and-cataklysim).

Comment: this worked for me.thanx for your time